# An object in Google Cloud Storage which acts as a "redirect" or "symlink"

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I'm looking to move an existing website to Google Cloud Storage. However, that existing website has changed its URL structure a few times in the past. These changes are currently handled by Apache: for example, the URL /days/000233.html redirects to /days/new-post-name and /days/new-post-name redirects to /days/2002/01/01/new-post-name. Similarly, /index.rss redirects to /feed.xml, and so on.

Is there a way of marking an object in GCS so that it acts as a "symlink" to another GCS object in the same bucket? That is, when I add website configuration to a bucket, requesting an object (ideally) generates a 301 redirect header to a different object, or (less ideally) serves the content of the other object as its own?

I don't want to simply duplicate the object at each URL, because that would triple my storage space. I also can't use meta refresh headers inside the object content, because some of the redirected objects are not HTML documents (they are images, or RSS feeds). For similar reasons, I can't handle this inside the NotFound 404.html with JavaScript.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Unfortunately, symlink functionality is currently not supported by Google Cloud Storage. It's a good idea though and worth considering as a future feature.

Comment: Now 2014, a future has come! Any plan for a symlink like feature for GCS?

Comment: yeah my s3 urls included the bucket name in the path as well as the dns, so when switching all my urls are out of date, so this would be nice.

Comment: It would be great to serve the actual content i.e just like a real symlink

Comment: 2017 here, any news from this?

Comment: More than 7 years after this answer, is there anything new?

Comment: 2020 it is. Are we in the future?

Comment: More than 8 years now. Are we there yet?

Comment: 2021 now, I posted a feature request here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/179289196

Comment: Hi, guys. It's your pal 2022 checking in!

Comment: I'm Mr 2024, also still waiting for this feature.