# Creating symbolic link in google cloud storage using java API

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-compute-engine

I am using **JSON API - Google API Client Library** for Java for reading the objects from **Google Cloud Storage**. I need to create a symbolic link for in the Bucket's internal content.

**EX:**
 
Assume that, the Bucket Contents will be like this
FolderA/
FolderA/FolderB/
FolderC/
--------------------------
I need to create a link like this
FolderC/ should point to FolderA/FolderB/
FolderC/-> FolderA/FolderB/

If anybody knows how to create symbolic links using the Java in Cloud Bucket, Please let me know.
(**Note:** without mounting the bucket in local filesystem)

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't. See [An object in Google Cloud Storage which acts as a “redirect” or “symlink”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12564669/an-object-in-google-cloud-storage-which-acts-as-a-redirect-or-symlink).

When you create a symlink in a mounted folder, you will upload a copy to cloud storage. If you change either you will have inconsistencies.